# HCF $(x,y) = 16$ and LCM $(x,y) = 48000$. Then the possible number of pairs $(x,y)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

Let $S$ be the set of all ordered pairs $(x,y)$ of positive integers, with HCF $(x,y) = 16$ and LCM $(x,y) = 48000$. The
number of elements in $S$ is

My Attempt : $48000= 2^7. 3 . 5^3$  As the L.c.m contains $2^7$ as a factor and G.c.d contains $2^4$ as a factor , we can assure that one element contains $2^7$ and the other one contains $2^4$. And $3$ and $5^3$ will be divided between two numbers in a manner so that the L.C.M and G.C.D remain as given.

So the possible pairs are $(2^7 .3 . 5^3 , 2^4)$ , $(2^7 .3 , 5^3.2^4)$ , $(2^7 , 3.5^3.2^4)$ , $(2^7.5^3 , 3.2^4)$.

So I think the number of elements in the set $S$ is $4$. Have I gone wrong anywhere? Can anyone please help me ?

Comment: Don't forget that the problem asks for ordered pairs, so if $(x,y)$ works you need to include $(y,x)$ as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a$ and $b$ be positive integers with the following prime factorisations:
$$ a = p_1^{\alpha_1} \ldots p_r^{\alpha_r} $$
and
$$ b = p_1^{\beta_1} \ldots p_r^{\beta_r}, $$
where $p_1, \ldots, p_r$ are prime numbers such that 
$$ p_1 < \cdots < p_r, $$
and $\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_r$ and $\beta_1, \ldots, \beta_r$ are non-negative integers.

Then 
$$ \mbox{GCD}(a, b) = p_1^{\min\left\{ \alpha_1, \beta_1 \right\}} \ldots p_r^{\min\left\{ \alpha_r, \beta_r \right\}} $$
and
$$ \mbox{LCM}(a, b) = p_1^{\max\left\{ \alpha_1, \beta_1 \right\}} \ldots p_r^{\max\left\{ \alpha_r, \beta_r \right\}}. $$

Thus in your case $a$ and $b$ are any positive integers such that 
$$ \mbox{GCD}(a, b) = 16 = 2^4 = 2^4 3^0  5^0, $$
and 
$$ \mbox{LCM}(a, b) = 48000 = 2^7 3^1 5^3. $$
Note that here we have chosen only those prime numbers that are factors of at least one of the LCM and the GCD of $a$ and $b$.

Thus 
$$ a = 2^{\alpha_1} 3^{\alpha_2} 5^{\alpha_3}, $$
and 
$$ b = 2^{\beta_1} 3^{\beta_2} 5^{\beta_3}, $$
where $\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \alpha_3, \beta_1, \beta_2, \beta_3$ are non-negative integers such that
$$ \min \left\{ \alpha_1, \beta_1 \right\} = 4, \qquad \min \left\{ \alpha_2, \beta_2 \right\} = 0, \qquad \min \left\{ \alpha_3, \beta_3 \right\} = 0, $$
and 
$$ \max \left\{ \alpha_1, \beta_1 \right\} = 7, \qquad \max \left\{ \alpha_2, \beta_2 \right\} = 1, \qquad \max \left\{ \alpha_3, \beta_3 \right\} = 3. $$

Thus we have the following ordered pairs $(a, b)$ of positive integers which satisfy the given conditions:
$$ \left( 2^4 3^0 5^0, 2^7 3^1 5^3 \right), \qquad \left( 2^4 3^0 5^3, 2^7 3^1 5^0 \right), \qquad \left( 2^4 3^1 5^0, 2^7 3^0 5^3 \right), \qquad \left( 2^7 3^0 5^0, 2^4 3^1 5^3 \right), \qquad \left( 2^4 3^1 5^3, 2^7 3^0 5^0 \right), \qquad \left( 2^7 3^0 5^3, 2^4 3^1 5^0 \right), \qquad  \left( 2^7 3^1 5^0, 2^4 3^0 5^3 \right), \qquad \left( 2^7 3^1 5^3, 2^4 3^0 5^0 \right),  $$
that is,
$$ (16, 48000), \qquad (2000, 384), \qquad (48, 16000), \qquad (128, 6000), \qquad (6000, 128), \qquad (16000, 48), \qquad (384, 2000), \qquad (48000, 16). $$

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 5):

Let $m$ and $n$ be positive integers such that $m\mid n$.  Then the number of solutions $(x,y)$ of positive integers $x,y$ such that
$$\gcd(x,y)=m$$
and
$$\operatorname{lcm}(x,y)=n$$
is
$$2^{\omega(n/m)},$$
where $\omega$ is the prime $\omega$-function, namely, $\omega(d)$ is the number of distinct prime divisors of $d$ (e.g., $\omega(1)=0$, $\omega(9)=1$, $\omega(12)=2$).  For a proof, each prime $p$ dividing $n/m$ has two choices, namely,

- $p^{s_p} \parallel x$ and $p^{t_p}\parallel y$, or
- $p^{t_p}\parallel x$ and $p^{s_p}\parallel y$.

Here, $p^k \parallel d$ if $p^k\mid d$ but $p^{k+1}\nmid d$, and $s_p$ and $t_p$ are such that $p^{s_p}\parallel m$ and $p^{t_p}\parallel n$.

In particular, for $m=16$ and $n=48000$, we have
$$\frac{n}{m}=3000=2^3\cdot 3\cdot 5^3$$
so that $\omega(n/m)=3$.  Hence, the answer is $2^3=8$.

If the number of unordered pairs $\{x,y\}$ is to be calculated or if you require that $x\leq y$, then the answer is
$$\left\lceil 2^{\omega\left(\frac{n}{m}\right)-1}\right\rceil\,.$$
(Normally, you wouldn't need the ceiling function.  It is needed only in the special case where $m=n$.)  In particular, for $m=16$ and $n=48000$, the number of solutions with $x\leq y$ is $\frac{2^3}{2}=4$.

Answer (score 1):

If $$\gcd(x,y)=16=2^4$$ and $$\operatorname{lcm}(x,y)=48000=2^7\cdot3\cdot5^3$$ then $$xy=2^{11}\cdot3\cdot5^3$$

So we can let 
$$x = 2^\alpha\cdot3^\beta\cdot5^\gamma \qquad \text{and} \qquad
  y = 2^{11-\alpha}\cdot3^{1-\beta}\cdot5^{3-\gamma}$$

We need

$$\begin{align}
   \min(\alpha, 11-\alpha) &= 4 \\
   \max(\alpha, 11-\alpha) &= 7 \\
   \min(\beta, 1-\beta) &= 0 \\
   \max(\beta, 1-\beta) &= 1 \\
   \min(\gamma, 3-\gamma) &= 0 \\
   \max(\gamma, 3-\gamma) &= 3
\end{align}$$

So $$\begin{align}
   \alpha &\in \{4,7\} \\
   \beta &\in \{0,1\} \\
   \gamma &\in \{0,3\}
\end{align}$$

So there are $2\cdot2\cdot2 = 8$ possible $(x,y)$ pairs.

Answer (score 0):

WLOG let $\dfrac xX=\dfrac yY=16$ so that $(X,Y)=1$

We have $48000\cdot16=xy=16^2XY\iff XY=3000=3\cdot2^3\cdot5^3$

So, the possible values of $X$ can be

take none of the factors $$1$$

take one of the factors $$3;2^3;5^3$$

take two of the factors $$2^3\cdot5^3;3\cdot5^3;2^3\cdot3$$

take all three of the factors $$3\cdot2^3\cdot5^3$$